# File Chooser display with a button click. Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jfilechooser, jform-designer

I have a Java assignment in which I need to build a program for exchanging information between students. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and a plugin called JFormDesigner for designing the GUI. I want do display a file chooser when clicking on a button. I have tried different implementations but non of them works. Nothing is displayed on the screen when clicking the button I was wondering if someone could help me find a solution.

This is the button code:

```
 ChooseButton1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                ChooseButton1MouseClicked(e);
            }
        });
```

This is the method where actions are implemented:

```
private void ChooseButton1MouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
    }
}
```

Here is test code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import java.io.*;

public class Test extends JPanel {

private JButton ChooseButton;

public Test() {
    initComponents();
}

private void ChooseButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
    }
}

private void initComponents() {

    ChooseButton = new JButton();


    setBorder(new javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder(
                                                           new javax.swing.border.TitledBorder(new javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0),
            "JFormDesigner Evaluation", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER,
            javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM, new java.awt.Font("Dialog", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12),
            java.awt.Color.red), getBorder())); addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener(){public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        if("border".equals(e.getPropertyName())) throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    });


    //---- ChooseButton ----
    ChooseButton.setText("Choose");
    ChooseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ChooseButtonActionPerformed(e);
        }
    });

    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
    setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                                     layout.createParallelGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                              .addGap(155, 155, 155)
                              .addComponent(ChooseButton)
                              .addContainerGap(175, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
                                   layout.createParallelGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(125, 125, 125)
                .addComponent(ChooseButton)
                .addContainerGap(143, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}

 public void main(String[] args) {

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            new Test();
        }

};
    EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
}

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) For buttons, use an `ActionListener` rather than `MouseListener`..

Comment: I tried using an ActionListener but the result is the same. Nothing happens

Comment: What @AndrewThompson is telling you is that likely the code you're showing is not telling us what you could be doing wrong, that you should create and post a small compilable and runnable example program, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that we can test and modify, that shows us your problem and that we can hep you fix.

Comment: And yeah, never use a MouseListener in place of an ActionListener.

Comment: *"Here is test code:"*  Without a `main(String[])` method it is not runnable or verifiable (so not an MCVE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose another listener

```
ChooseButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ChooseButton1MouseClicked(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: 1+ as this is good advice, although he'll need to change his chooseButton.... parameter type. I can only hope that this will solve his problem.

Comment: I believe it could be solved in many ways, nice suggestion but I'm not sure if I need to modify it either.